# Checkbox increasing value in database

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, isset

Yes this is one of those checkbox Form questions.
Im trying to keep my question short and simple to understand.
I have a form with about 25 checkboxes, divided into 3 groups. Each group gives a different point for each checked box. Group1 = 5points/check | Group2 = 8points/check | Group3 = 12points/check. What I want to do is to count number of checks on submit and then add everything to a total score. Simple? New boxes can be checked at any time, which means that the total score can increase, and to make it easier, checkboxes can't be unchecked so the total score can't decrease. The total score will then be saved in a database table. This is what i've got right now, it's not much, but I need new eyes on my problem. The equation seems easy in my head, but I can't get it on paper.

```
            ....5points
                    <label for="first_name">first point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="five[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['five'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />

                    <label for="first_name">sec point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="five[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['five'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />

                    <label for="first_name">n point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="five[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['five'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
................8points
                    <label for="first_name">first point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eight[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['eight'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />

                    <label for="first_name">sec point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eight[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['eight'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
....12points and so on
```

also Im saving the boxes as checked with the **Isset = checked** code.
This is my ugly addition of total score:

```
$a =0;
$b =0;
$total;
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if (isset($_POST['five'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['five'] as $five) {
       $a + 5;
    }
 if (isset($_POST['eight'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['eight'] as $eight) {
       $b + 8;
    }
    $total=$total+$a+$b;
}
```

But of course it does not do the trick, it just gives me an echo result as 5555555 and 888888. Also I don't want my total to add the same score twice which it seems to do now. Can someone help me straight this brain teaser out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change $a + 5 and $a + 8 to:

```
$a += 5;
$a += 8;
```

Or you can make the whole counting even smarter, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
  $fives = isset($_POST['five']) ? $_POST['five'] : array();
  $eights = isset($_POST['eight']) ? $_POST['eight'] : array();
  $twelves = isset($_POST['twelve']) ? $_POST['twelve'] : array();

  $total = 5 * count($fives) + 8 * count($eights) + 12 * count(twelves);
}
```

Also, your html propbly checks all the checkboxes if submitted. Change the if statements, names, and add disabled property if you don't want points to be substracted:

```
            ....5points
                    <label for="first_name">first point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="five[0]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['five'][0])) echo 'checked="checked" disabled="true"'; ?> />

                    <label for="first_name">sec point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="five[1]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['five'][1])) echo 'checked="checked" disabled="true"'; ?> />

                    <label for="first_name">n point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="five[2]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['five'][2])) echo 'checked="checked" disabled="true"'; ?> />
................8points
                    <label for="first_name">first point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eight[0]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['eight'][0])) echo 'checked="checked" disabled="true"'; ?> />

                    <label for="first_name">sec point</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eight[1]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['eight'][1])) echo 'checked="checked" disabled="true"'; ?> />
....12points and so on
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't think of using count at all. Nice solution.

Comment: This is great! but if I don't choose any twelve point checkboxes i get value undefined? And another question, can the checkboxes checked and disabled even after reload the page? @Ziarno

Comment: Yes they should be checked and disabled after reloading now. For example if you don't choose any of the 'five' checkboxes then this array will be empty and 5 * count($_POST['five']) = 0

Comment: Im sorry but when I hit the page without entering on of each checkbox, ive get an error, either total undefined or some of the other once undefined. And when I got to the index page and then back the checkboxes does not want to stay checked :/

Comment: hmm right, if you don't check any then $_POST['five'] is not set and throws and error. Let me edit a little

Comment: made it a little longer though, because you need to check each variable if it exists, if not assign and empty array

Comment: Great! This is really great thanks! Still have a tiny winy little problem, when I click submit again the total counter resets and the checkboxes unchecks, any hint of what to search for?

Comment: or im thinking, if I save the total to a DB after submit, then I have to retrive it and add to it the next time. shouldnt be harder then that?

Comment: you can save the $total in DB, but then you won't know which checkboxes were clicked. If you want to always get checked/disabled checkboxes you need to save some values in your DB that would keep track of which ones the user clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your PHP code, here's an example:

```
$total = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['five'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['five'] as $five) {
            $total += 5;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['eight'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['eight'] as $eight) {
            $total += 8;
        }
    }
}
```

The `+=` operator takes a variable, `$total` in this case, and adds to it whatever comes on the right side. So `$total += 8;` is the same thing as `$total = $total + 8;`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your foreach loop you are just doing $a + 5 and $b + 8, you probably want to write $a +=5, $b += 8

Answer (score 0):

replace `$a + 5;` and `$b + 8;` with below

```
$a += 5;
$b += 8;
```